# Handling back press in fragment with finish functionality same as activities

Tags: android, android-fragments, onbackpressed

I need help to detail with fragments. I have 5 fragments(in one activity) like:

[1], [2], [3], [4], [5]

I go from 1 -> 2, then 2 -> 3 and so on. User able to come back like 3 -> 2 and it is fine.

When i reach at 5th fragment, on 5th fragment i have a "Submit" button , i want when i click on submit i redirect to fragment 1 and then if user click back press it not go to 5th again. Like user complete a circle and go to back after completing a circle.

Same like we do in activities with "finish".

Answer (score 0):

Do you use Android Navigation or do you just add the fragments using `FragmentManager`? In case of `FragmentManager`, if you want to finish the activity whenever user press back button on your first fragment, then in your activity class, just do:

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
    if (supportFragmentManager.fragments.last() is FirstFragment) {
        finish()
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed()
    }
}
```

This should be the java equivalent, but revise before trying out, as my java is a bit rusty:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    int fragmentsCount = fm.getFragments().size();
    if (fragmentsCount > 0 &&
            fm.getFragments().get(fragmentsCount - 1) instanceof FirstFragment) {
        finish();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```